# Fails to Compile C# project due to primary reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm trying to compile the project with targeted framework as ".NETFramework 4.0". But I get the following warning:

> The primary reference "XXX" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the framework assembly
>   "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the
>   currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve
>   this problem, either remove the reference "Fdi" or retarget your
>   application to a framework version which contains
>   "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

Answer (score 2):

I found an earlier (but similar) problem: [Visual Studio 2010: Reference Assemblies Targeting Higher Framework Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298577/visual-studio-2010-reference-assemblies-targeting-higher-framework-version)

Johannes Rudolph found this answer on MSDN's forums ( http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/dfadfb34-5328-4c53-8274-931c6ae00836 ):

> However, there're 2 workarounds.
>
> Option 1:
>
> Step1: Unload the referencing project targeting .NET 2.0
>
> Step2: Right click the unloaded project and select edit from context menu
>
> Step3: Add `<SpecificVersion>true</SpecificVersion>` to the reference. 
>   Below is a sample from my repro solution:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\HighFX\HighFX.csproj">
<Project>{8DD71CAF-BEF7-40ED-9DD0-25033CD8009D}</Project>
<Name>HighFX</Name>
<SpecificVersion>true</SpecificVersion>
</ProjectReference>
```

> Step4: Reload the project.
>    Now your should be able to build within the Visual Studio 2010, there could still be a warning as below, but the build can be successful.
>
> Warning 1 The project 'XXX' cannot be referenced.  The referenced project is targeted to a higher framework version (3.5)
>
> Option2:
>
> Use the command line tool csc.exe to build each of your source file, which won't prevent the building.