# Visual Studio 2010 and dotnet framework v2.0 unable to compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2010 to open a dotnet framework 2.0 web application. The conversion looks ok, all the target platform has been set to v2.0

However, during rebuilding of solution it complains the references(dll) i have added requires a later version of dotnet framework.

All the dll are build using dotnet framework 2.0 many years back, it is impossible for it to require a later version

I am clueless in resolving this.

a) This is the message I get when I rebuild the solution.
The type or namespace name xxx does not exist in the namespace xxx (are you missing an assembly or reference?)

b) This is the message I get when I try to re-add the DLL as a reference
xxx.dll or one of its dependencies, requires a later version of the .NET framework than the one specified in the project.

You can change the .NET framework target by clicking Properties on the Project menu and then selecting a new target in the .NET Framework dropdown box.

Comment: Please include the exact text of the compiler error message.  *"It complains"* is not relevant -- the exact error message is.

Comment: sorry, my bad at describing errors.

Comment: do you have the .NET framework 2.0 installed on your development machine? if you don't have the .dlls available, visual studio will try to replace them with the ones available in the GAC, which may or may not be linked with other higher versions of the framework.

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party libraries that you are using (CryatalReports maybe)? You might have a newer version of the 3rd party library installed on your computer where you are trying to build that solution which targets a newer .NET framework

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 10g previously and Crystal Report 2005. However, I have stored all the reference DLL in a folder as reference path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3298577/327083